# How to add two drawableRight in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable

I am able to add one `drawableRight` in `EditText` in android easly and on click event working perfectly in case of one `drawableRight`. But I need two `drawableRight` in `EditText`.

So, How can I add two `drawableRight` in `EditText`? and I also need to perform click event on both `drawableRight` separately.
For example I want to add yellow star in `EditText` like as given below image and on click on rightmost image I want to open contact book of phone and on click of yellow star I want to call user's favourite numbers list.

So How can I do this? Any Idea?

[image: multiple drawable]

Comment: you would need to use relativeLayout.

Comment: use relativeLayout and set a line under the relativeLayout like your image.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native support for this, so you got two options here:

**Easy solution:** Create a Linear layout with tow image views on the right side, those will be your drawables.

**The hard way:** Extend a `Drawable` class and implement your own `onDraw` method where you will draw the two drawables. Than use that one for your text view.

Comment: If you take the 'hard' way - which isn't actually that hard - make sure to also implement the setBounds to have space for both drawables.

Comment: Though if you want different click methods for each drawable, the easy way is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The `TextView` can contain only one drawable on either of its sides. The only options you have are:

1. Create custom `View`.
2. Take some of the `ViewGroup` descendants (`RelativeLayout`/`FrameLayout`/etc) and put the TextView along with the two `ImageView`s in it.

Answer (score -1):

Just place two Drawables into EditText using RelativeLayout.
To set inner padding, place an invisible drawableRight into EditText:

**/res/values/dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="iconSize">32dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**/res/layout/my_layout.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/iconSize"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/iconSize"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_1"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/iconSize"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/iconSize"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**In your Activity:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    int iconSize = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.iconSize)

    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_action_1);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, iconSize * 2, 0); // that is the trick!

    editText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, drawable, null);

 }
```